# how do i use the httpClient POST in java

Tags: java, arrays, http, post

im trying to http post to a rest api where i need the post content to be like this

```
{
  "_id": "string",
  "minDuration": 0,
  "maxDuration": 0,
  "calculatedMaxLimitDuration": 0,
}
```

but i dont know much about java and arrays(i guess) as im use to php and havent coded in years so what should i put in the .POST() ???

```
public class App {

    static String lockId = "secret";

    private static final  String POSTS_API_URL = "Url" + lockId + "/update-time";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .POST()
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer secret")
                .uri(URI.create(POSTS_API_URL))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create that json as a String and put it into the body of the request.

Comment: You need to use `.POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(yourJsonString))`

Comment: @f1sh is there a way to make a array in to a Json string? like in php i can make a associative array like this
`array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43")`
and then convert that in to a Json string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use RestTemplate or WebClient to call the API, it would be easy !

**A snippet as below**

```
{
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity <String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
      
      return restTemplate.exchange("
         http://serviceToCall:8080/endPoint", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
   }
```

Read more about restTemplate here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_rest_template.htm